# Can't check the checkbox of GCP to increase "Queries per 100 seconds per user" of Google drive api

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-developers-console

[image: 1]

my mouse can't check the checkbox in the picture to increase "Queries per 100 seconds per user" of Google drive api.

what could be the reason for this? I have followed the instructions to join a paid account.

Comment: Have you enabling billing on this project? Check out this [quotas documentation](https://cloud.google.com/docs/quota#requesting_higher_quota) where it specifies that billing must be enabled on that project.

Comment: @MateoRandwolf drive api is a free api it does not require billing.

Comment: I could select and edit this quota on one of my projects. Once you select it you can choose a new quota limit between 0 and 1000 for your project (in this specific limit). Now that I think to reduce quotas I don't think you would need to enable billing. @ZhenNesl could you try clearing cookies refreshing and trying again to select the checkbox? Also, were you trying to increase or reduce this quota limit?

Answer (score 0):

> "Queries per 100 seconds per user"

is a user based quota and can not be increased.  Only the project based quotas can be increased.